# CentOS 7 - Qt creator can't parse .pro files

Tags: qt, qt-creator, centos7

Qt creator is exhibiting this behavior on a fresh installation of CentOS 7:

Once a `.pro` file is opened, this message is displayed, and the project fails to load:

```
/usr/lib64/qt5/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf(70): system(execute requires one or two arguments. 

Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'g++'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment? 

Error while parsing file /online/RCCARS/compass-rccars-daq/compass-rccars-daq-master/Master.pro. Giving up.
```

Upon googling a bit, I found that commenting out the following line:

```
load(toolchain)
```

In this file:

```
/usr/lib64/qt5/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf
```

solves this issue. After doing this, I can once again open projects, as well as compile and run them without any issues.

I checked the `g++` path as well, it is correct and in fact points to a `g++` compiler.

The question is, why does this happen? Could commenting the line out have any negative effects? Are there any alternative solutions?